# Why my email address link copy then paste to another system and then this is not working?

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, pop3

My email link https://login
which is not open to another system how and why?
but another links easily open why ?

Comment: What is your problem? What should you link to? It is the link to the google mail inbox. If someone is logged in, he will see his inbox, if not he will first have to log in.

Comment: thanx to advice

Comment: but my question is that when any gmail login link is copy and then paste to another computer then why that person's email-id is not login ?

Comment: It worked for me? So what exactly is the problem. Also `https://login` is not a valid url as far as I am aware